# Multiple Page PHP Variable

Tags: php, html

I need help creating a variable that sits in a file that the client never visits, that can be read by any page on my site.
Note: this variable is involved in the include processes for other PHP files on the pages in question, therefore include that is not an option

Comment: Just `include` the page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Perhaps you will want to enhance your question first; it's not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you answer is **Session**

The session support allows you to store data between requests in the $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if session.auto_start is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through session_start() or implicitly through session_register()) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.

**Attn :** Because session data is serialized, **resource** variables cannot be stored in the session.

Comment: It isn't working unless i'm doing something wrong: set value with: session_start();
$_SESSION['Value']= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] Retrieve value with:  "include($_SESSION['Value'].'inc/header.php') -Thanks

Comment: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is already a variable that is always available. no need to store it in a session.